Integrating a Ktor backend with Jetpack Compose
I'm new to Kotlin and would like to know how to integrate a backend with Ktor into my Jetpack Compose application.
I've already created a back office in Next.js with Prisma to manage the data in my Postgres database. I would now like to create another API in my mobile application so that it can connect to my database and handle CRUD operations.
This project is also a way of learning Kotlin, but if you think my decisions and technology choices are wrong, please let me know. Thank you for your feedback.

Just for clarity, you want to use Ktor to execute service calls?

This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. In general, though, you'll want to structure your application in layers. Compose is on the top layer and will not get in contact with the data layer where your network access would take place. See https://ktor.io/docs/client-create-new-application.html if you want to learn how to create a Ktor client. Then pass the retrieved data up through the layers using Flows, into the UI where you'll eventually collect the flows and display the data.

I realise that I haven't explained my problem properly.
I've created a project with Jetpack Compose with a simple UI. Now I would like to create an API within the same project to execute requests.
I'm aware of the concept of layers. I would like to create a layer that would make requests on my database, and this layer would be called by another one that would behave like a service and return the data to my views. I don't know if this respects the MVVM architecture perfectly, but I would like to do something like that.

@ImEmo This is still too broad. It actually has nothing to do with Compose, since network operations are independent from UI in real applications.
First of all you should learn how data layers interact with Ktor, I believe you can easily find information on that
